# Loading a dynamically created radio button list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to generate a dynamic radio button list, but the issue is that the dynamic list does not show on page load. Only the Submit button shows. Here is the code I am using:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"/>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadControls();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radioButtonList = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("1") as RadioButtonList;
        Label1.Text = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
    }

    private void LoadControls()
    {
        var tmpRBL = new RadioButtonList();
        tmpRBL.ID = "1";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var tmpItem = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
            tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem);
        }

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpRBL);
    }
```

Comment: Try putting it in a `UpdatePanel`

Comment: That code should work just fine, make sure you don't have another `control` that may be interfering with your `render`.

Comment: I have tried Update Panel but it did not solved my problem.I have no other control that may be interfing

Answer (score 0):

WebForm1.aspx

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadControls();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var radioButtonList = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("1") as RadioButtonList;
            Label1.Text = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
        }

        private void LoadControls()
        {
            var tmpRBL = new RadioButtonList();
            tmpRBL.ID = "1";

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                var tmpItem = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem);
            }

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpRBL);
        }
    }
}
```

It works correct. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply..Issue did not solved yet by using solution suggested by you

Comment: What are you using on page except this controls and code? In your question are not any issues.

Comment: There is no other control except above .I need to generate dynamic  radio list and event handler for displaying selected value of radio button list  control

Answer (score 0):

You could define an empty RadioButtonList control which you then populate with items on Page_Load. Would have the advantage that you don't have to create it manually. Also using the DataBind mechanism the control offers you together with an ObjectDataSource is a better solution (the Select method of the ObjectDataSource should return the items).

But aside this, maybe `AutoEventWireup` of the @Page directive (first line in the markup of the ASPX page) is set to false. If so the `Page_Load` event handler is not called. The directive usually looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```

I copied the rest of your code and everything runs just fine.